# que hago para que no se me superponga esta wave?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Busco que la wave no se pare encima del texto, sino que si el texto llega a su lugar, esta se vaya mas abajo así no se superponga... o lo que encuentren más conveniente.
Intenté ponerlo dentro de un div y darle margin-top, tambien lo hice con el div del texto: darle margin-bottom, entre otras cosas que no funcionaron, entre otras cosas que no funcionaron, entre otras cosas que no funcionaron.

**ARCHIVO CSS:**

```
/********Waves*********/

/*arreglar wave*/

.banner{
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(250, 67, 71, 0.8), rgba(250, 67, 71, 1)), url("https://images.contentstack.io/v3/assets/blt187521ff0727be24/bltc6e788b11a9c8245/60ee0f71a86d0f5a0be449a3/MissFortune_0.jpg");
    height: 100vh;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    position:relative; /*?*/
} 

.banner .waves{
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width: 100%;
    left:0;
}


/********Text*********/

h1, h2{
    color: #3b2e42;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

h1{
    font-size:4.5rem;
}

h2{
    font-size:2.5rem;
}


/********Profile picture*********/

.profile-pic{
    width: 43vh;
    height: 43vh;
    margin-top: 10vh;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
}
  
.profile-pic img{
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**ARCHIVO HTML:**

```
<header class="banner">
    
    <div class="container-fluid text-center">
      <div class="profile-pic">
        <img 
        src="https://64.media.tumblr.com/8c4f60b89afc2d206ec9fef93558e985/94356f32c2506702-ba/s500x750/3809cb778e4e8cf867f1e6bb233b98e9fc1f98aa.jpg" 
        alt="profile picture"/> <!--rellenar dato-->
      </div>
      <h1>MISS FORTUNE</h1>  <!--rellenar dato-->
      <h2>Desarrolladora Web Full-Stack Jr.</h2>  <!--rellenar dato-->
    </div>
    <div class="wave">
      <svg class="waves"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 320"><path fill="#3b2e42" fill-opacity="1" d="M0,128L80,160C160,192,320,256,480,234.7C640,213,800,107,960,96C1120,85,1280,171,1360,213.3L1440,256L1440,320L1360,320C1280,320,1120,320,960,320C800,320,640,320,480,320C320,320,160,320,80,320L0,320Z"></path>
      </svg>
    </div>
</header>
```

Utilicé Bootstrap.

**-----PROBANDO RESPUESTAS:-----**

`<svg class="waves fixed-bottom position-relative"...</svg>`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y si le agrego `.banner{ height: 115vh; }`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Intentaste con svg: class="waves fixed-bottom position-relative" ?

Comment: @René acabo de probarlo y subí mis resultados, casi! siento que tengo que modificarle algo y a lo mejor funciona

Comment: Buen día, puedes adjuntar tu HTML y CSS completo?... recuerda que es mejor adjuntar un ejemplo [mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Cris223511.dev listo, actualicé el css. el html está completo, no tiene el !doctype y eso porque es un componente de angular. ademas recuerden que uso bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como la posición del `waves` es `absolute`, los textos (en resoluciones pequeñas) no van a poder empujar al elemento `waves` hacia abajo porque tiene una posición fija y es absoluta, haciendo que el texto esté detrás del `waves`:

```
.banner .waves{
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0;
  width: 100%;
  left:0;
}
```

Solo dejemos que el elemento sea relativo para que los elementos no se desborden y no estén uno encima del otro:

```
.banner .waves {
  position: relative;
}
```

Y el problema también sucedía por la altura fija del `banner`, tiene solo un alto de `100vh`, por la cual, en resoluciones pequeñas, ese alto seguirá siendo `100vh` y tus elementos se desbordarán fuera del `banner`, solo indiquemos que ocupe el máximo contenido que pueda (con `max-content`), así nunca se va a desbordar sus elementos y a que `banner` ocuparía el alto máximo posible:

```
.banner {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(250, 67, 71, 0.8), rgba(250, 67, 71, 1)),
    url('https://images.contentstack.io/v3/assets/blt187521ff0727be24/bltc6e788b11a9c8245/60ee0f71a86d0f5a0be449a3/MissFortune_0.jpg');
  /* height: 100vh; */
  height: max-content;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
```

---

Código completo:

```css
/********Waves*********/

/*arreglar wave*/

.banner {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(250, 67, 71, 0.8), rgba(250, 67, 71, 1)),
    url('https://images.contentstack.io/v3/assets/blt187521ff0727be24/bltc6e788b11a9c8245/60ee0f71a86d0f5a0be449a3/MissFortune_0.jpg');
  height: max-content;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative; /*?*/
}

.banner .waves {
  position: relative;
}

/********Text*********/

h1,
h2 {
  color: #3b2e42;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 4.5rem;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}

.titulos {
  text-align: center;
}

/********Profile picture*********/

.imagen {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.profile-pic {
  width: 43vh;
  height: 43vh;
  margin-top: 10vh;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

.profile-pic img {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header class="banner">

  <div class="container-fluid text-center">
    <div class="imagen">
      <div class="profile-pic">
        <img 
             src="https://64.media.tumblr.com/8c4f60b89afc2d206ec9fef93558e985/94356f32c2506702-ba/s500x750/3809cb778e4e8cf867f1e6bb233b98e9fc1f98aa.jpg" 
             alt="profile picture"/> <!--rellenar dato-->
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="titulos">
      <h1>MISS FORTUNE</h1>  <!--rellenar dato-->
      <h2>Desarrolladora Web Full-Stack Jr.</h2>  <!--rellenar dato-->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wave">
    <svg class="waves"
         xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 320"><path fill="#3b2e42" fill-opacity="1" d="M0,128L80,160C160,192,320,256,480,234.7C640,213,800,107,960,96C1120,85,1280,171,1360,213.3L1440,256L1440,320L1360,320C1280,320,1120,320,960,320C800,320,640,320,480,320C320,320,160,320,80,320L0,320Z"></path>
    </svg>
  </div>
</header>
```

---

Puedes ver mejor los resultados en [**éste enlace**](https://codepen.io/christopher-ps/pen/ZEqWZjp).